# rotate the number rendering against the camera

Tags: c++, opengl, rotation, render, particles

I have this function to draw numbers above a character.

```
void RenderNumber(vec3_t Position,int Num,vec3_t Color,float Alpha,float Scale)
{
    vec3_t p;
    VectorCopy(Position,p);
    vec3_t Light[4];
    VectorCopy(Color,Light[0]);
    VectorCopy(Color,Light[1]);
    VectorCopy(Color,Light[2]);
    VectorCopy(Color,Light[3]);
    if(Num == -1)
    {
        float UV[4][2];
        TEXCOORD(UV[0],0.f       ,32.f/32.f);
        TEXCOORD(UV[1],32.f/256.f,32.f/32.f);
        TEXCOORD(UV[2],32.f/256.f,17.f/32.f);
        TEXCOORD(UV[3],0.f       ,17.f/32.f);
        RenderSpriteUV(BITMAP_FONT+1,p,45,20,UV,Light,Alpha);
    }
    else if(Num == -2)
    {
        RenderSprite(BITMAP_FONT_HIT,p,32*Scale,20*Scale, Light[0], 0.f, 0.f, 0.f, 27.f/32.f, 15.f/16.f);   
    }
    else
    {
        char Text[32];
        itoa(Num,Text,10);
        p[0] -= strlen(Text)*5.f;
        unsigned int Length = strlen(Text);
        p[0] -= Length*Scale*0.125f;
        p[1] -= Length*Scale*0.125f;
        for(unsigned int i=0;i<Length;i++)
        {
            float UV[4][2];
            float u = (float)(Text[i]-48)*16.f/256.f;
            TEXCOORD(UV[0],u           ,16.f/32.f);
            TEXCOORD(UV[1],u+16.f/256.f,16.f/32.f);
            TEXCOORD(UV[2],u+16.f/256.f,0.f);
            TEXCOORD(UV[3],u           ,0.f);
            RenderSpriteUV(BITMAP_FONT+1,p,Scale,Scale,UV,Light,Alpha);
            p[0] += Scale*0.5f;
            p[1] += Scale*0.5f;
        }
    }
}
```

I created a 3D camera that rotates around the character. Everything is rendered correctly, but the rendering of these numbers that indicate the received hit is rendered without rotation.

```
void RenderSpriteUV(int Texture,vec3_t Position,float Width,float Height,float (*UV)[2],vec3_t Light[4],float Alpha)
{
    BindTexture(Texture);

    vec3_t p2;
    VectorTransform(Position,CameraMatrix,p2);
    float x = p2[0];
    float y = p2[1];
    float z = p2[2];
    
    Width  *= 0.5f;
    Height *= 0.5f;
    vec3_t p[4];
    Vector(x-Width, y-Height, z, p[0]);
    Vector(x+Width, y-Height, z, p[1]);
    Vector(x+Width, y+Height, z, p[2]);
    Vector(x-Width, y+Height, z, p[3]);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        glColor4f(Light[i][0],Light[i][1],Light[i][2],Alpha);
        glTexCoord2f(UV[i][0],UV[i][1]);
        glTexCoord3f(UV[i][0],UV[i][1],100.f);
        glVertex3fv(p[i]);
    }
    glEnd();
}
```

I would need to point the numbers towards the camera so that they are easily readable at any camera angle.

Now if I rotate the camera (Y) the camera also rotates around the numbers.

Is there any way to do it?

To render, I call these functions first

```
void CreatePoint(vec3_t Position,int Value,vec3_t Color,float scale, bool bMove, bool bRepeatedly)
{
    for(int i=0;i<MAX_POINTS;i++)
    {
        PARTICLE *o = &Points[i];
        if(!o->Live)
        {
            o->Live = true;
            o->Type = Value;
            VectorCopy(Position,o->Position);
            o->Position[2] += 140.f;
            VectorCopy(Color,o->Color);
            o->bRepeatedly = bRepeatedly;
            o->fRepeatedlyHeight = RequestTerrainHeight(o->Position[0], o->Position[1])+140.0f;
            o->Gravity  = 10.f;
            o->Scale    = scale;
            o->LifeTime = 0;
            o->bEnableMove = bMove;
            return;
        }
    }
}

void RenderPoints( BYTE byRenderOneMore )
{
    EnableAlphaTest();
    DisableDepthTest();
    for(int i=0;i<MAX_POINTS;i++)
    {
        PARTICLE *o = &Points[i];
        if(o->Live)
        {
            if ( byRenderOneMore==1 )
            {
                if ( o->Position[2]>350.f ) continue;
            }
            else if ( byRenderOneMore==2 )
            {
                if ( o->Position[2]<=300.f ) continue;
            }
            else if(o->bRepeatedly)
            {
                if( o->Position[2] <= o->fRepeatedlyHeight) continue;
            }
            RenderNumber(o->Position,o->Type,o->Color,o->Gravity*0.4f,o->Scale);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to set the rotation but I couldn't set it correctly.

Comment: Rotate the numbers the opposite of the camera rotation

Comment: Yes, I know that.
I just don't know how to write it.

Comment: Are you familiar with matrices? Instead of trying to calculate the position for each number, use a matrix which translates 0,0,0 to the position where you want them to render, and render the number at 0,0,0. Then you can 'stack' other matrices as well, like a rotation matrix.

Comment: Okay, I'm really at the end now.

Can I ask for an example of how to modify these functions so that I can rotate the camera and the numbers I draw are still in the same position?

Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure how to explain it properly without writing your code for you and testing it. You know how you have a camera rotation that rotates *everything* in the world and you don't have to work out the rotation separately for every individual thing? Because you use a matrix?

Comment: Do you mean camera movement?
I have it solved like this. I just add and subtract from CameraAngle[2] when moving the camera.

=>"
            vec3_t angle = { 0.f, 0.f, -45.f };
      Vector ( 0.f, g_fCameraCustomDistance, 0.f, Position );
      AngleMatrix ( angle, Matrix );
      VectorIRotate ( Position, Matrix, TransformPosition );
      VectorAdd ( CameraPosition, TransformPosition, CameraPosition );
"<=
I don't need tested code, but just an example to guide me in the right direction.

Comment: Yeah, this CameraMatrix thing. You know how you just create the CameraMatrix one time, and then you just transform all your vectors by the CameraMatrix? You can have more than one matrix. You can make a NumberFacingCameraMatrix, and then have your number vectors, and transform by the NumberFacingCameraMatrix, and then the CameraMatrix. Unfortunately I really don't know how to explain this properly. This was common in OpenGL 1 tutorials since OpenGL 1 forced people to do their transformations like this.

Comment: Ok, I guess I described the problem wrong and I already know which part is wrong.
Individual numbers are turned towards the camera. As you rotate the 3D camera around the character, the position for each number changes depending on the Scale. The numbers begin to overlap and the order of the numbers is reversed.
Now the question is how to calculate the value of p[0] and p[1] so that the correct position is maintained when the camera moves.

Comment: Because you should rotate the whole group of numbers instead of each separate number